# How To get Value when zooming in Telerik chart?

Tags: asp.net, charts, telerik, zooming

I'm trying to use chart Zoom event in Asp.net. How can I obtain x-y values from Chart Zoom event args ?

First of all I  bind a data to my chart after user zooms, according to the zoom args I want to bind another data source to chart because of performance issue. How can I manage my plan ?

tnx.